# Возможно ли использовать в проектах типа - .dll файлы ресурсов (.resx) для хранения текста показываемого пользователю при генерации ошибок?

Tags: c#, ресурсы

Иногда при написании текстов описывающих возникшую в коде ошибку, мы сталкиваемся с тем, что данный текст, дублируется от ошибки к ошибке в разных блоках кода. Порой, при редактировании кода либо при банальном желании перефразировать написанный ранее текст ошибки возникает необходимость отредактировать текст сопровождающий ошибку. Поскольку один и тот же текст может быть раскидан по нескольким файлам, процесс редактирования сопровождающего ошибку текста превращается в боль.

1. **Возможно ли использовать в проектах типа - .dll файлы ресурсов (.resx) для хранения текста показываемого пользователю при генерации ошибок?** (Я знаю, что технически это возможно в WPF. Но не знаю, есть ли какие технические нюансы при работе с данными файлами в .dll).
2. **Является ли нормальной практикой использование файлов .resx для хранения текста ошибок?**
3. Если возможно прокомментируйте существующие альтернативы по упрощению работы с дублирующимся текстом ошибок.

П.С: Я знаю, что файлы ресурсов (.resx) предназначены для локализации. Просто хочу услышать мнения о появившейся в голове идее, упрощающей работу с текстом ошибок.

Comment: resx - для локализации, не для устранения дублирования. Устранять дублирование проще подпрограммами или константами.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы порекомендуете хранить константы внутри классов в которых указываются ошибки либо в отдельном файле едином для всего проекта? Второе решение в виде реализации подпрограмм, если честно, вообще с трудом представляется. Подскажите есть ли какие то статьи или примеры?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я как то быстро сдал назад, после вашего комментария о назначении .resx файлов, мысленно откинув идею. Но вспомнил, что текст ошибок показываемый конечному пользователю, иногда так же нуждается в локализации. Так что возможно все же, использование файлов ресурсов это нормальная альтернатива константам?

Comment: Для целей локализации - да, совершенно нормальная. Более того, это официальная альтернатива константам.